# Entity translation service implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, entity, dto

I have an asp.net application that communicates with a WCF.
the WCF messages are represented in DTO classes.

to get the data from **WCF** I have to translate the **DTO** messages to a View **DTO** classes in order to be viewed in the application.

I remember there was an entity translation service at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304747.aspx)

but now the article says that the content is retired and moved to Web Service Software Factory.

I searched for the same service in WSSF but with no luck.
is there a new replacement for this service ??? or is there a better implementation for the **Entity Translation Service** ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the [Glue](http://glue.codeplex.com/) library for entity mapping in my project. [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) and [enter link description here](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) are some other popular libraries you can use.

Glue doesn't handle subclass mapping yet; but I prefer it over AutoMapper (which can map subclasses correctly). The way AutoMapper handles its configuration is too black-box like and error prone IMHO.

Comment: Actually I'm aware of AutoMapper, ValueInjecter, but do these libraries considered as Entity Translation Service ?? which means I don't need to use the code of Microsoft's entity translation service if I use them, right?